# Why can I see the background color through the pixel elements of the SVG picture?

Tags: xml, svg, pixel

Background color breaking through the pixel elements creating blue outline around every pixel of the elements (see the picture).

https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic63db736220b17300967112

## Markup

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 -0.5 180 180" shape-rendering="crispyEdges" >
    <rect fill="#2aaaff" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="180" />
    <path stroke="#fbf236" d="M64 21h1M66 21h1M94 21h1M97 21h1M101 21h1M114 21h1M64 22h1M66 22h1M94 22h1M97 22h1M101 22h1M114 22h1M64 23h1M94 23h1M97 23h1M101 23h1M114 23h1M64 24h1M68 24h1M84 24h1M94 24h1M97 24h1M101 24h1M114 24h1M64 25h1M68 25h2M71 25h1M84 25h2M87 25h1M90 25h3M94 25h1M97 25h2M101 25h3M107 25h2M112 25h3M64 26h1M68 26h1M70 26h1M72 26h1M84 26h1M86 26h1M88 26h1M90 26h1M94 26h1M97 26h1M101 26h1M104 26h1M106 26h1M109 26h1M111 26h1M114 26h1M64 27h1M68 27h1M70 27h1M72 27h1M84 27h1M86 27h1M88 27h1M90 27h2M94 27h1M97 27h1M101 27h1M104 27h1M106 27h1M109 27h1M111 27h1M114 27h1M64 28h1M68 28h1M70 28h1M72 28h1M84 28h1M86 28h1M88 28h1M90 28h3M95 28h1M98 28h2M101 28h1M104 28h1M107 28h2M111 28h4M89 41h1M91 41h1M93 41h1M84 42h5M90 42h1M84 43h2M87 43h6M94 43h1M96 43h1M98 43h1M81 44h2M84 44h5M90 44h1M92 44h2M95 44h1M97 44h1M80 45h1M82 45h5M88 45h4M93 45h3M97 45h1M99 45h1M101 45h1M79 46h16M96 46h3M77 47h21M99 47h1M101 47h1M104 47h1M76 48h1M78 48h1M80 48h9M90 48h2M93 48h2M96 48h5M102 48h1M76 49h24M101 49h3M106 49h1M75 50h28M104 50h1M74 51h1M76 51h1M78 51h24M103 51h3M108 51h1M73 52h32M106 52h1M74 53h30M105 53h3M72 54h2M75 54h1M77 54h28M106 54h1M108 54h1M73 55h31M105 55h1M107 55h1M71 56h2M74 56h8M88 56h12M106 56h3M72 57h2M75 57h6M89 57h11M107 57h1M109 57h1M71 58h1M73 58h7M89 58h10M108 58h1M70 59h1M72 59h4M77 59h3M90 59h9M109 59h1M71 60h1M73 60h7M90 60h8M108 60h1M110 60h1M70 61h1M72 61h8M90 61h8M109 61h1M69 62h1M71 62h9M90 62h8M108 62h1M110 62h1M70 63h1M72 63h2M75 63h5M90 63h8M108 63h1M110 63h1M69 64h1M71 64h9M90 64h8M108 64h2M70 65h9M90 65h7M108 65h1M110 65h1M68 66h2M71 66h9M89 66h9M107 66h1M109 66h1M69 67h3M73 67h6M89 67h8M107 67h2M68 68h1M70 68h9M88 68h9M106 68h2M109 68h1M68 69h10M87 69h9M105 69h5M67 70h2M70 70h8M87 70h9M105 70h2M108 70h1M68 71h3M72 71h5M86 71h9M104 71h4M67 72h2M70 72h7M86 72h8M104 72h5M66 73h1M68 73h8M85 73h9M103 73h2M106 73h2M67 74h2M70 74h5M85 74h8M102 74h4M107 74h1M66 75h1M68 75h3M72 75h3M84 75h8M102 75h5M67 76h2M70 76h2M73 76h2M84 76h8M101 76h3M105 76h2M112 76h1M66 77h1M68 77h3M72 77h3M83 77h9M101 77h4M106 77h1M112 77h1M67 78h1M70 78h2M73 78h2M83 78h9M100 78h6M112 78h1M68 79h3M72 79h4M83 79h10M100 79h2M103 79h3M111 79h1M69 80h1M73 80h5M82 80h13M99 80h4M104 80h1M111 80h1M71 81h1M74 81h31M113 81h1M73 82h1M75 82h26M102 82h2M110 82h2M74 83h1M76 83h1M78 83h1M80 83h3M84 83h3M88 83h1M90 83h12M103 83h2M110 83h1M112 83h1M79 84h1M83 84h1M87 84h1M89 84h1M91 84h1M96 84h7M110 84h2M95 85h1M99 85h5M110 85h3M81 86h1M83 86h1M86 86h1M88 86h1M90 86h1M92 86h9M102 86h1M110 86h4M71 87h1M73 87h1M76 87h1M78 87h2M81 87h2M84 87h10M95 87h7M111 87h2M69 88h1M72 88h1M75 88h24M103 88h1M67 89h1M69 89h1M71 89h4M79 89h21M102 89h1M68 90h1M70 90h1M72 90h4M78 90h23M103 90h1M69 91h1M71 91h1M73 91h4M78 91h24M104 91h1M69 92h8M79 92h23M105 92h1M68 93h1M70 93h1M72 93h6M80 93h23M106 93h1M69 94h1M71 94h1M73 94h6M80 94h24M105 94h1M107 94h1M70 95h1M72 95h1M74 95h5M81 95h23M106 95h1M108 95h1M71 96h1M73 96h7M82 96h23M107 96h1M72 97h1M74 97h1M76 97h5M82 97h23M108 97h1M73 98h1M75 98h6M83 98h23M109 98h1M75 99h7M83 99h24M108 99h1M74 100h3M78 100h4M83 100h24M109 100h1M76 101h6M84 101h23M110 101h1M75 102h1M77 102h6M84 102h24M109 102h1M111 102h1M76 103h7M85 103h23M109 103h2M77 104h2M80 104h4M85 104h23M110 104h2M78 105h6M86 105h23M110 105h1M112 105h1M78 106h7M86 106h23M110 106h2M79 107h7M87 107h22M110 107h1M112 107h1M79 108h2M82 108h4M87 108h22M110 108h2M78 109h1M80 109h6M87 109h22M110 109h2M62 110h1M79 110h7M87 110h22M110 110h3M62 111h1M70 111h1M80 111h6M87 111h21M110 111h2M113 111h1M61 112h2M69 112h1M71 112h1M80 112h1M82 112h4M88 112h20M109 112h4M62 113h1M79 113h8M88 113h20M109 113h4M70 114h1M80 114h7M88 114h20M109 114h4M80 115h7M88 115h19M109 115h4M80 116h2M83 116h4M88 116h19M108 116h5M81 117h6M88 117h18M108 117h4M80 118h1M82 118h6M89 118h16M107 118h5M81 119h7M89 119h16M106 119h5M80 120h1M82 120h1M84 120h4M90 120h14M106 120h5M83 121h6M91 121h12M105 121h5M111 121h1M82 122h8M93 122h8M104 122h5M111 122h1M84 123h1M86 123h6M94 123h5M102 123h6M111 123h1M82 124h1M85 124h8M100 124h7M111 124h1M85 125h2M88 125h18M111 125h1M87 126h1M89 126h16M111 126h1M86 127h1M88 127h1M90 127h13M111 127h1M92 128h9M110 128h2M110 129h3M93 130h1M110 130h3M78 131h1M92 131h1M110 131h3M78 132h1M92 132h1M110 132h4M78 133h2M91 133h2M110 133h4M77 134h3M91 134h2M110 134h5M77 135h3M91 135h2M110 135h5M77 136h3M91 136h3M110 136h2M113 136h2M77 137h3M91 137h4M111 137h2M114 137h2M77 138h3M90 138h3M94 138h1M110 138h4M115 138h1M77 139h3M91 139h3M111 139h2M115 139h1M76 140h4M90 140h4M111 140h3M115 140h1M76 141h4M91 141h3M112 141h4M76 142h4M91 142h4M112 142h4M76 143h2M79 143h1M92 143h2M111 143h5M75 144h3M92 144h3M112 144h4M76 145h3M92 145h3M112 145h3M75 146h5M92 146h3M113 146h1M75 147h5M76 148h5M76 149h4M76 150h5M77 151h4M77 152h4M78 153h3" />
    <path stroke="#ffffff" d="M82 21h1M82 22h1M81 23h1M81 24h1M80 25h1M80 26h1M79 27h1M79 28h1M88 41h1M90 41h1M92 41h1M94 41h5M89 42h1M91 42h11M83 43h1M86 43h1M93 43h1M95 43h1M97 43h1M99 43h5M89 44h1M91 44h1M94 44h1M96 44h1M98 44h7M87 45h1M92 45h1M96 45h1M98 45h1M100 45h1M102 45h4M95 46h1M99 46h8M98 47h1M100 47h1M102 47h2M105 47h3M89 48h1M92 48h1M95 48h1M101 48h1M103 48h6M100 49h1M104 49h2M107 49h3M103 50h1M105 50h5M102 51h1M106 51h2M109 51h2M105 52h1M107 52h4M104 53h1M108 53h4M105 54h1M107 54h1M109 54h3M104 55h1M106 55h1M108 55h4M87 56h1M105 56h1M109 56h4M88 57h1M106 57h1M108 57h1M110 57h3M107 58h1M109 58h4M108 59h1M110 59h3M109 60h1M111 60h2M108 61h1M110 61h3M109 62h1M111 62h2M109 63h1M111 63h2M110 64h3M109 65h1M111 65h2M108 66h1M110 66h3M109 67h4M108 68h1M110 68h2M110 69h2M107 70h1M109 70h2M108 71h3M109 72h1M105 73h1M108 73h2M106 74h1M108 74h1M107 75h2M104 76h1M107 76h2M105 77h1M107 77h1M106 78h2M102 79h1M106 79h2M112 79h1M103 80h1M105 80h2M112 80h1M105 81h2M111 81h2M101 82h1M104 82h3M112 82h2M102 83h1M105 83h1M111 83h1M113 83h1M103 84h3M112 84h2M104 85h1M113 85h1M101 86h1M103 86h2M102 87h3M113 87h1M104 88h1M103 89h3M104 90h2M103 91h1M105 91h2M104 92h1M106 92h2M105 93h1M107 93h2M106 94h1M108 94h2M107 95h1M109 95h1M106 96h1M108 96h3M107 97h1M109 97h2M108 98h1M110 98h2M109 99h3M108 100h1M110 100h2M109 101h1M111 101h2M110 102h1M112 102h1M111 103h3M112 104h2M111 105h1M113 105h1M112 106h2M111 107h1M113 107h1M112 108h2M112 109h2M113 110h1M112 111h1M70 112h1M113 112h1M70 113h1M113 113h1M113 114h1M112 136h1M113 137h1M93 138h1M114 138h1M94 139h1M113 139h2M94 140h1M114 140h1M94 141h1M78 143h1M94 143h1M78 144h2M79 145h1M80 146h1M80 147h1M80 149h1" />
    <path stroke="#c2882b" d="M81 41h2M79 42h2M77 43h2M76 44h2M75 45h2M74 46h2M73 47h2M72 48h2M71 49h2M71 50h1M70 51h1M69 52h2M69 53h1M68 54h2M68 55h1M68 56h1M67 57h1M67 58h1M66 59h1M66 60h1M65 61h1M65 62h1M65 63h1M64 64h1M64 65h1M64 66h1M63 67h1M63 68h1M63 69h1M62 70h1M62 71h1M62 72h1M62 73h1M62 74h1M61 75h2M61 76h2M61 77h2M61 78h2M60 79h2M60 80h2M110 80h1M60 81h2M110 81h1M60 82h2M109 82h1M60 83h2M109 83h1M60 84h2M109 84h1M60 85h2M60 86h2M60 87h2M60 88h2M60 89h2M60 90h3M61 91h2M61 92h2M61 93h3M62 94h2M63 95h2M63 96h3M64 97h2M65 98h2M62 99h1M66 99h2M62 100h1M67 100h2M61 101h2M68 101h2M62 102h1M69 102h1M62 103h1M69 103h2M60 104h3M69 104h2M60 105h1M62 105h1M69 105h3M60 106h1M62 106h1M69 106h1M71 106h2M60 107h1M62 107h1M69 107h1M71 107h3M59 108h2M62 108h1M69 108h1M73 108h1M59 109h2M63 109h1M69 109h1M74 109h1M60 110h1M63 110h1M69 110h1M74 110h1M59 111h2M63 111h1M68 111h1M59 112h2M63 112h1M68 112h1M75 112h1M60 113h1M63 113h1M68 113h1M75 113h1M60 114h1M63 114h1M68 114h1M75 114h1M60 115h2M63 115h1M69 115h1M75 115h1M60 116h4M69 116h1M75 116h1M61 117h3M70 117h1M75 117h1M62 118h2M75 118h1M75 119h1M75 120h1M76 121h1M76 122h1M77 123h1M112 123h1M77 124h1M112 124h1M109 125h2M112 125h1M79 126h1M108 126h1M112 126h1M79 127h1M106 127h2M112 127h1M80 128h1M105 128h1M112 128h1M113 129h1M80 130h1M113 130h1M80 131h1M113 131h1M80 132h1M109 132h1M114 132h1M80 133h1M109 133h1M114 133h1M108 134h1M115 134h1M108 135h1M115 135h1M89 136h1M108 136h1M115 136h1M89 137h1M108 137h1M116 137h1M108 138h2M116 138h1M89 139h1M108 139h2M116 139h1M89 140h1M109 140h1M116 140h1M89 141h1M116 141h1M89 142h1M110 142h1M116 142h1M74 143h1M110 143h1M116 143h1M110 144h1M116 144h1M91 145h1M115 145h1M91 146h1M111 146h1M114 146h1M74 147h1M92 147h1M94 147h1M114 147h1M74 148h1M112 148h2M74 149h1M74 150h1M74 151h1M80 155h1M78 156h2"></path>
    <path stroke="#ffb743" d="M83 41h5M81 42h3M79 43h4M78 44h3M83 44h1M77 45h3M81 45h1M76 46h3M75 47h2M74 48h2M77 48h1M79 48h1M73 49h3M72 50h3M71 51h3M75 51h1M77 51h1M71 52h2M70 53h4M70 54h2M74 54h1M76 54h1M69 55h4M69 56h2M73 56h1M82 56h1M100 56h1M68 57h4M74 57h1M81 57h1M68 58h3M72 58h1M80 58h1M99 58h1M67 59h3M71 59h1M76 59h1M80 59h1M67 60h4M72 60h1M80 60h1M98 60h1M66 61h4M71 61h1M80 61h1M98 61h1M66 62h3M70 62h1M80 62h1M98 62h1M66 63h4M71 63h1M74 63h1M80 63h1M98 63h1M65 64h4M70 64h1M80 64h1M98 64h1M65 65h5M79 65h2M97 65h2M65 66h3M70 66h1M80 66h1M98 66h1M64 67h5M72 67h1M79 67h2M97 67h2M64 68h4M69 68h1M79 68h1M97 68h1M64 69h4M78 69h1M96 69h1M63 70h4M69 70h1M78 70h1M96 70h1M63 71h5M71 71h1M77 71h1M95 71h1M63 72h4M69 72h1M94 72h1M63 73h3M67 73h1M76 73h1M94 73h1M63 74h4M69 74h1M75 74h2M93 74h1M63 75h3M67 75h1M71 75h1M75 75h1M92 75h2M63 76h4M69 76h1M72 76h1M75 76h1M92 76h1M63 77h3M67 77h1M71 77h1M75 77h1M92 77h1M63 78h4M68 78h2M72 78h1M75 78h1M92 78h1M111 78h1M62 79h6M71 79h1M76 79h1M93 79h1M62 80h7M70 80h3M62 81h9M72 81h2M62 82h11M74 82h1M62 83h12M75 83h1M77 83h1M79 83h1M83 83h1M87 83h1M89 83h1M62 84h17M80 84h3M84 84h3M88 84h1M90 84h1M92 84h4M62 85h33M96 85h3M62 86h19M82 86h1M84 86h2M87 86h1M89 86h1M91 86h1M62 87h9M72 87h1M74 87h2M77 87h1M80 87h1M83 87h1M94 87h1M62 88h7M70 88h2M73 88h2M111 88h3M62 89h5M68 89h1M70 89h1M111 89h2M63 90h5M69 90h1M71 90h1M63 91h6M70 91h1M72 91h1M63 92h6M64 93h4M69 93h1M71 93h1M64 94h5M70 94h1M72 94h1M65 95h5M71 95h1M73 95h1M66 96h5M72 96h1M66 97h6M73 97h1M75 97h1M67 98h6M74 98h1M68 99h7M69 100h5M77 100h1M70 101h6M70 102h5M76 102h1M71 103h5M71 104h6M79 104h1M72 105h6M70 106h1M73 106h5M70 107h1M74 107h5M74 108h5M81 108h1M75 109h3M79 109h1M75 110h4M75 111h5M76 112h4M81 112h1M76 113h3M76 114h4M76 115h4M76 116h4M82 116h1M113 116h1M76 117h5M76 118h4M76 119h4M76 120h4M81 120h1M83 120h1M111 120h1M77 121h6M77 122h4M110 122h1M78 123h6M85 123h1M109 123h2M78 124h4M83 124h2M108 124h3M79 125h3M83 125h2M87 125h1M107 125h2M80 126h7M88 126h1M105 126h3M80 127h6M87 127h1M89 127h1M103 127h3M79 128h1M81 128h11M101 128h4M79 129h1M82 129h20M79 130h1M87 130h6M94 130h7M79 131h1M79 132h1 M111 70h1M111 71h1M110 72h1M110 73h1M109 74h1M109 75h1M109 76h1M108 77h1M108 78h1M108 79h1M107 80h1M107 81h1M107 82h1M106 83h1M106 84h1M105 85h1M105 86h1M105 87h1M105 88h1M106 89h1M106 90h1M107 91h1M108 92h1M109 93h1M110 94h1M110 95h1M111 96h1M111 97h1M112 98h1M112 99h1M112 100h1M113 101h1M113 102h1M114 103h1M114 104h1M61 105h1M114 105h1M61 106h1M114 106h1M61 107h1M114 107h1M61 108h1M70 108h1M114 108h1M61 109h2M70 109h1M114 109h1M61 110h1M70 110h1M114 110h1M61 111h1M69 111h1M114 111h1M114 112h1M61 113h1M69 113h1M71 113h1M114 113h1M61 114h2M69 114h1M71 114h1M114 114h1M62 115h1M70 115h2M113 115h2M70 116h1M114 116h1M112 117h3M81 118h1M112 118h2M80 119h1M111 119h3M112 120h1M110 121h1M112 121h1M81 122h1M109 122h1M112 122h1M108 123h1M107 124h1M82 125h1M106 125h1M93 131h1M91 132h1M90 133h1M80 134h1M90 134h1M93 134h1M109 134h1M80 135h1M90 135h1M93 135h1M109 135h1M76 136h1M80 136h1M90 136h1M94 136h1M109 136h1M76 137h1M80 137h1M90 137h1M95 137h1M109 137h2M76 138h1M80 138h1M89 138h1M95 138h1M76 139h1M80 139h1M90 139h1M95 139h1M110 139h1M75 140h1M80 140h1M95 140h1M110 140h1M75 141h1M80 141h1M90 141h1M95 141h1M110 141h2M75 142h1M80 142h1M90 142h1M95 142h1M111 142h1M75 143h1M80 143h1M90 143h2M95 143h1M74 144h1M80 144h1M91 144h1M95 144h1M111 144h1M74 145h2M80 145h1M95 145h1M111 145h1M74 146h1M81 146h1M95 146h1M112 146h1M81 147h1M93 147h1M112 147h2M75 148h1M81 148h1M75 149h1M81 149h1M75 150h1M81 150h1M75 151h2M81 151h1M75 152h2M81 152h1M76 153h2M81 153h1M76 154h6M77 155h3"></path>
    <path stroke="#a17124" d="M78 42h1M76 43h1M75 44h1M74 45h1M73 46h1M72 47h1M71 48h1M70 50h1M69 51h1M68 52h1M68 53h1M67 54h1M67 55h1M66 56h2M66 57h1M65 58h2M65 59h1M64 60h2M64 61h1M64 62h1M63 63h2M63 64h1M63 65h1M62 66h2M62 67h1M62 68h1M61 69h2M61 70h1M61 71h1M61 72h1M61 73h1M60 74h2M60 75h1M60 76h1M60 77h1M59 78h2M59 79h1M59 80h1M59 81h1M59 82h1M59 83h1M59 84h1M59 85h1M109 85h1M59 86h1M109 86h1M59 87h1M109 87h2M59 88h1M110 88h1M59 89h1M59 90h1M60 91h1M60 92h1M60 93h1M60 94h2M60 95h3M60 96h3M60 97h4M60 98h5M60 99h2M65 99h1M60 100h2M66 100h1M60 101h1M67 101h1M60 102h2M68 102h1M60 103h2M68 103h1M59 104h1M59 105h1M58 106h2M58 107h2M58 108h1M72 108h1M58 109h1M73 109h1M58 110h2M68 110h1M73 110h1M58 111h1M74 111h1M58 112h1M67 112h1M74 112h1M58 113h2M67 113h1M74 113h1M58 114h2M67 114h1M74 114h1M58 115h2M68 115h1M74 115h1M58 116h2M68 116h1M74 116h1M59 117h2M69 117h1M74 117h1M60 118h2M74 118h1M74 119h1M74 120h1M75 121h1M75 122h1M76 123h1M76 124h1M77 125h2M78 126h1M110 126h1M78 127h1M110 127h1M78 128h1M109 128h1M78 129h1M80 129h2M102 129h3M109 129h1M78 130h1M82 130h5M101 130h1M109 130h1M77 131h1M87 131h5M94 131h8M109 131h1M77 132h1M90 132h1M93 132h1M77 133h1M93 133h1M76 134h1M89 134h1M76 135h1M89 135h1M75 136h1M75 137h1M75 138h1M88 138h1M75 139h1M88 139h1M74 140h1M88 140h1M74 141h1M88 141h1M109 141h1M74 142h1M88 142h1M109 142h1M89 143h1M109 143h1M73 144h1M90 144h1M109 144h1M73 145h1M90 145h1M110 145h1M73 146h1M90 146h1M110 146h1M73 147h1M91 147h1M111 147h1M73 148h1M92 148h2M111 148h1M73 149h1M73 150h1M73 151h1M74 152h1M75 153h1M75 154h1M76 155h1M77 156h1"></path>
    <path stroke="#000000" d="M83 56h4M101 56h4M82 57h6M100 57h6M81 58h8M100 58h7M81 59h9M99 59h9M81 60h9M99 60h9M81 61h9M99 61h9M81 62h9M99 62h9M81 63h9M99 63h9M81 64h9M99 64h9M81 65h9M99 65h9M81 66h8M99 66h8M81 67h8M99 67h8M80 68h8M98 68h8M79 69h8M97 69h8M79 70h8M97 70h8M78 71h8M96 71h8M77 72h9M95 72h9M77 73h8M95 73h8M77 74h8M94 74h8M76 75h8M94 75h8M76 76h8M93 76h8M76 77h7M93 77h8M76 78h7M93 78h7M77 79h6M94 79h6M78 80h4M95 80h4M99 88h4M75 89h4M100 89h2M76 90h2M101 90h2M77 91h1M102 91h1M77 92h2M102 92h2M78 93h2M103 93h2M79 94h1M104 94h1M79 95h2M104 95h2M80 96h2M105 96h1M81 97h1M105 97h2M81 98h2M106 98h2M82 99h1M107 99h1M82 100h1M107 100h1M82 101h2M107 101h2M83 102h1M108 102h1M83 103h2M108 103h1M84 104h1M108 104h2M84 105h2M109 105h1M85 106h1M109 106h1M86 107h1M109 107h1M86 108h1M109 108h1M86 109h1M109 109h1M86 110h1M109 110h1M86 111h1M108 111h2M86 112h2M108 112h1M87 113h1M108 113h1M87 114h1M108 114h1M87 115h1M107 115h2M87 116h1M107 116h1M87 117h1M106 117h2M88 118h1M105 118h2M88 119h1M105 119h1M88 120h2M104 120h2M89 121h2M103 121h2M90 122h3M101 122h3M92 123h2M99 123h3M93 124h7"></path>
</svg>
```

I want to get clean svg picture with no outlines around pixels of picture elements as if it was a png picture.

Comment: Your path are looking like _move to point, horizontal line, move to point, horozontal line ...etc_ I'ts like an pattern for a fabric. No matter what you will do it will look pixelated. It was designed to look like so.

Comment: crispEdges, not crispyEdges

Comment: Does it solve the problem if you replace `shape-rendering="crispyEdges"` with `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` like @RobertLongson suggests?

Comment: yeah it helped well!

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake in your shape-rendering attribute.

Try shape-rendering="crispEdges" instead of shape-rendering="crispyEdges".

As you can see below, the edges are cleaned up when applying this change:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 -0.5 180 180" shape-rendering="crispEdges" >
    <rect fill="#2aaaff" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="180" />
    <path stroke="#fbf236" d="M64 21h1M66 21h1M94 21h1M97 21h1M101 21h1M114 21h1M64 22h1M66 22h1M94 22h1M97 22h1M101 22h1M114 22h1M64 23h1M94 23h1M97 23h1M101 23h1M114 23h1M64 24h1M68 24h1M84 24h1M94 24h1M97 24h1M101 24h1M114 24h1M64 25h1M68 25h2M71 25h1M84 25h2M87 25h1M90 25h3M94 25h1M97 25h2M101 25h3M107 25h2M112 25h3M64 26h1M68 26h1M70 26h1M72 26h1M84 26h1M86 26h1M88 26h1M90 26h1M94 26h1M97 26h1M101 26h1M104 26h1M106 26h1M109 26h1M111 26h1M114 26h1M64 27h1M68 27h1M70 27h1M72 27h1M84 27h1M86 27h1M88 27h1M90 27h2M94 27h1M97 27h1M101 27h1M104 27h1M106 27h1M109 27h1M111 27h1M114 27h1M64 28h1M68 28h1M70 28h1M72 28h1M84 28h1M86 28h1M88 28h1M90 28h3M95 28h1M98 28h2M101 28h1M104 28h1M107 28h2M111 28h4M89 41h1M91 41h1M93 41h1M84 42h5M90 42h1M84 43h2M87 43h6M94 43h1M96 43h1M98 43h1M81 44h2M84 44h5M90 44h1M92 44h2M95 44h1M97 44h1M80 45h1M82 45h5M88 45h4M93 45h3M97 45h1M99 45h1M101 45h1M79 46h16M96 46h3M77 47h21M99 47h1M101 47h1M104 47h1M76 48h1M78 48h1M80 48h9M90 48h2M93 48h2M96 48h5M102 48h1M76 49h24M101 49h3M106 49h1M75 50h28M104 50h1M74 51h1M76 51h1M78 51h24M103 51h3M108 51h1M73 52h32M106 52h1M74 53h30M105 53h3M72 54h2M75 54h1M77 54h28M106 54h1M108 54h1M73 55h31M105 55h1M107 55h1M71 56h2M74 56h8M88 56h12M106 56h3M72 57h2M75 57h6M89 57h11M107 57h1M109 57h1M71 58h1M73 58h7M89 58h10M108 58h1M70 59h1M72 59h4M77 59h3M90 59h9M109 59h1M71 60h1M73 60h7M90 60h8M108 60h1M110 60h1M70 61h1M72 61h8M90 61h8M109 61h1M69 62h1M71 62h9M90 62h8M108 62h1M110 62h1M70 63h1M72 63h2M75 63h5M90 63h8M108 63h1M110 63h1M69 64h1M71 64h9M90 64h8M108 64h2M70 65h9M90 65h7M108 65h1M110 65h1M68 66h2M71 66h9M89 66h9M107 66h1M109 66h1M69 67h3M73 67h6M89 67h8M107 67h2M68 68h1M70 68h9M88 68h9M106 68h2M109 68h1M68 69h10M87 69h9M105 69h5M67 70h2M70 70h8M87 70h9M105 70h2M108 70h1M68 71h3M72 71h5M86 71h9M104 71h4M67 72h2M70 72h7M86 72h8M104 72h5M66 73h1M68 73h8M85 73h9M103 73h2M106 73h2M67 74h2M70 74h5M85 74h8M102 74h4M107 74h1M66 75h1M68 75h3M72 75h3M84 75h8M102 75h5M67 76h2M70 76h2M73 76h2M84 76h8M101 76h3M105 76h2M112 76h1M66 77h1M68 77h3M72 77h3M83 77h9M101 77h4M106 77h1M112 77h1M67 78h1M70 78h2M73 78h2M83 78h9M100 78h6M112 78h1M68 79h3M72 79h4M83 79h10M100 79h2M103 79h3M111 79h1M69 80h1M73 80h5M82 80h13M99 80h4M104 80h1M111 80h1M71 81h1M74 81h31M113 81h1M73 82h1M75 82h26M102 82h2M110 82h2M74 83h1M76 83h1M78 83h1M80 83h3M84 83h3M88 83h1M90 83h12M103 83h2M110 83h1M112 83h1M79 84h1M83 84h1M87 84h1M89 84h1M91 84h1M96 84h7M110 84h2M95 85h1M99 85h5M110 85h3M81 86h1M83 86h1M86 86h1M88 86h1M90 86h1M92 86h9M102 86h1M110 86h4M71 87h1M73 87h1M76 87h1M78 87h2M81 87h2M84 87h10M95 87h7M111 87h2M69 88h1M72 88h1M75 88h24M103 88h1M67 89h1M69 89h1M71 89h4M79 89h21M102 89h1M68 90h1M70 90h1M72 90h4M78 90h23M103 90h1M69 91h1M71 91h1M73 91h4M78 91h24M104 91h1M69 92h8M79 92h23M105 92h1M68 93h1M70 93h1M72 93h6M80 93h23M106 93h1M69 94h1M71 94h1M73 94h6M80 94h24M105 94h1M107 94h1M70 95h1M72 95h1M74 95h5M81 95h23M106 95h1M108 95h1M71 96h1M73 96h7M82 96h23M107 96h1M72 97h1M74 97h1M76 97h5M82 97h23M108 97h1M73 98h1M75 98h6M83 98h23M109 98h1M75 99h7M83 99h24M108 99h1M74 100h3M78 100h4M83 100h24M109 100h1M76 101h6M84 101h23M110 101h1M75 102h1M77 102h6M84 102h24M109 102h1M111 102h1M76 103h7M85 103h23M109 103h2M77 104h2M80 104h4M85 104h23M110 104h2M78 105h6M86 105h23M110 105h1M112 105h1M78 106h7M86 106h23M110 106h2M79 107h7M87 107h22M110 107h1M112 107h1M79 108h2M82 108h4M87 108h22M110 108h2M78 109h1M80 109h6M87 109h22M110 109h2M62 110h1M79 110h7M87 110h22M110 110h3M62 111h1M70 111h1M80 111h6M87 111h21M110 111h2M113 111h1M61 112h2M69 112h1M71 112h1M80 112h1M82 112h4M88 112h20M109 112h4M62 113h1M79 113h8M88 113h20M109 113h4M70 114h1M80 114h7M88 114h20M109 114h4M80 115h7M88 115h19M109 115h4M80 116h2M83 116h4M88 116h19M108 116h5M81 117h6M88 117h18M108 117h4M80 118h1M82 118h6M89 118h16M107 118h5M81 119h7M89 119h16M106 119h5M80 120h1M82 120h1M84 120h4M90 120h14M106 120h5M83 121h6M91 121h12M105 121h5M111 121h1M82 122h8M93 122h8M104 122h5M111 122h1M84 123h1M86 123h6M94 123h5M102 123h6M111 123h1M82 124h1M85 124h8M100 124h7M111 124h1M85 125h2M88 125h18M111 125h1M87 126h1M89 126h16M111 126h1M86 127h1M88 127h1M90 127h13M111 127h1M92 128h9M110 128h2M110 129h3M93 130h1M110 130h3M78 131h1M92 131h1M110 131h3M78 132h1M92 132h1M110 132h4M78 133h2M91 133h2M110 133h4M77 134h3M91 134h2M110 134h5M77 135h3M91 135h2M110 135h5M77 136h3M91 136h3M110 136h2M113 136h2M77 137h3M91 137h4M111 137h2M114 137h2M77 138h3M90 138h3M94 138h1M110 138h4M115 138h1M77 139h3M91 139h3M111 139h2M115 139h1M76 140h4M90 140h4M111 140h3M115 140h1M76 141h4M91 141h3M112 141h4M76 142h4M91 142h4M112 142h4M76 143h2M79 143h1M92 143h2M111 143h5M75 144h3M92 144h3M112 144h4M76 145h3M92 145h3M112 145h3M75 146h5M92 146h3M113 146h1M75 147h5M76 148h5M76 149h4M76 150h5M77 151h4M77 152h4M78 153h3" />
    <path stroke="#ffffff" d="M82 21h1M82 22h1M81 23h1M81 24h1M80 25h1M80 26h1M79 27h1M79 28h1M88 41h1M90 41h1M92 41h1M94 41h5M89 42h1M91 42h11M83 43h1M86 43h1M93 43h1M95 43h1M97 43h1M99 43h5M89 44h1M91 44h1M94 44h1M96 44h1M98 44h7M87 45h1M92 45h1M96 45h1M98 45h1M100 45h1M102 45h4M95 46h1M99 46h8M98 47h1M100 47h1M102 47h2M105 47h3M89 48h1M92 48h1M95 48h1M101 48h1M103 48h6M100 49h1M104 49h2M107 49h3M103 50h1M105 50h5M102 51h1M106 51h2M109 51h2M105 52h1M107 52h4M104 53h1M108 53h4M105 54h1M107 54h1M109 54h3M104 55h1M106 55h1M108 55h4M87 56h1M105 56h1M109 56h4M88 57h1M106 57h1M108 57h1M110 57h3M107 58h1M109 58h4M108 59h1M110 59h3M109 60h1M111 60h2M108 61h1M110 61h3M109 62h1M111 62h2M109 63h1M111 63h2M110 64h3M109 65h1M111 65h2M108 66h1M110 66h3M109 67h4M108 68h1M110 68h2M110 69h2M107 70h1M109 70h2M108 71h3M109 72h1M105 73h1M108 73h2M106 74h1M108 74h1M107 75h2M104 76h1M107 76h2M105 77h1M107 77h1M106 78h2M102 79h1M106 79h2M112 79h1M103 80h1M105 80h2M112 80h1M105 81h2M111 81h2M101 82h1M104 82h3M112 82h2M102 83h1M105 83h1M111 83h1M113 83h1M103 84h3M112 84h2M104 85h1M113 85h1M101 86h1M103 86h2M102 87h3M113 87h1M104 88h1M103 89h3M104 90h2M103 91h1M105 91h2M104 92h1M106 92h2M105 93h1M107 93h2M106 94h1M108 94h2M107 95h1M109 95h1M106 96h1M108 96h3M107 97h1M109 97h2M108 98h1M110 98h2M109 99h3M108 100h1M110 100h2M109 101h1M111 101h2M110 102h1M112 102h1M111 103h3M112 104h2M111 105h1M113 105h1M112 106h2M111 107h1M113 107h1M112 108h2M112 109h2M113 110h1M112 111h1M70 112h1M113 112h1M70 113h1M113 113h1M113 114h1M112 136h1M113 137h1M93 138h1M114 138h1M94 139h1M113 139h2M94 140h1M114 140h1M94 141h1M78 143h1M94 143h1M78 144h2M79 145h1M80 146h1M80 147h1M80 149h1" />
    <path stroke="#c2882b" d="M81 41h2M79 42h2M77 43h2M76 44h2M75 45h2M74 46h2M73 47h2M72 48h2M71 49h2M71 50h1M70 51h1M69 52h2M69 53h1M68 54h2M68 55h1M68 56h1M67 57h1M67 58h1M66 59h1M66 60h1M65 61h1M65 62h1M65 63h1M64 64h1M64 65h1M64 66h1M63 67h1M63 68h1M63 69h1M62 70h1M62 71h1M62 72h1M62 73h1M62 74h1M61 75h2M61 76h2M61 77h2M61 78h2M60 79h2M60 80h2M110 80h1M60 81h2M110 81h1M60 82h2M109 82h1M60 83h2M109 83h1M60 84h2M109 84h1M60 85h2M60 86h2M60 87h2M60 88h2M60 89h2M60 90h3M61 91h2M61 92h2M61 93h3M62 94h2M63 95h2M63 96h3M64 97h2M65 98h2M62 99h1M66 99h2M62 100h1M67 100h2M61 101h2M68 101h2M62 102h1M69 102h1M62 103h1M69 103h2M60 104h3M69 104h2M60 105h1M62 105h1M69 105h3M60 106h1M62 106h1M69 106h1M71 106h2M60 107h1M62 107h1M69 107h1M71 107h3M59 108h2M62 108h1M69 108h1M73 108h1M59 109h2M63 109h1M69 109h1M74 109h1M60 110h1M63 110h1M69 110h1M74 110h1M59 111h2M63 111h1M68 111h1M59 112h2M63 112h1M68 112h1M75 112h1M60 113h1M63 113h1M68 113h1M75 113h1M60 114h1M63 114h1M68 114h1M75 114h1M60 115h2M63 115h1M69 115h1M75 115h1M60 116h4M69 116h1M75 116h1M61 117h3M70 117h1M75 117h1M62 118h2M75 118h1M75 119h1M75 120h1M76 121h1M76 122h1M77 123h1M112 123h1M77 124h1M112 124h1M109 125h2M112 125h1M79 126h1M108 126h1M112 126h1M79 127h1M106 127h2M112 127h1M80 128h1M105 128h1M112 128h1M113 129h1M80 130h1M113 130h1M80 131h1M113 131h1M80 132h1M109 132h1M114 132h1M80 133h1M109 133h1M114 133h1M108 134h1M115 134h1M108 135h1M115 135h1M89 136h1M108 136h1M115 136h1M89 137h1M108 137h1M116 137h1M108 138h2M116 138h1M89 139h1M108 139h2M116 139h1M89 140h1M109 140h1M116 140h1M89 141h1M116 141h1M89 142h1M110 142h1M116 142h1M74 143h1M110 143h1M116 143h1M110 144h1M116 144h1M91 145h1M115 145h1M91 146h1M111 146h1M114 146h1M74 147h1M92 147h1M94 147h1M114 147h1M74 148h1M112 148h2M74 149h1M74 150h1M74 151h1M80 155h1M78 156h2"></path>
    <path stroke="#ffb743" d="M83 41h5M81 42h3M79 43h4M78 44h3M83 44h1M77 45h3M81 45h1M76 46h3M75 47h2M74 48h2M77 48h1M79 48h1M73 49h3M72 50h3M71 51h3M75 51h1M77 51h1M71 52h2M70 53h4M70 54h2M74 54h1M76 54h1M69 55h4M69 56h2M73 56h1M82 56h1M100 56h1M68 57h4M74 57h1M81 57h1M68 58h3M72 58h1M80 58h1M99 58h1M67 59h3M71 59h1M76 59h1M80 59h1M67 60h4M72 60h1M80 60h1M98 60h1M66 61h4M71 61h1M80 61h1M98 61h1M66 62h3M70 62h1M80 62h1M98 62h1M66 63h4M71 63h1M74 63h1M80 63h1M98 63h1M65 64h4M70 64h1M80 64h1M98 64h1M65 65h5M79 65h2M97 65h2M65 66h3M70 66h1M80 66h1M98 66h1M64 67h5M72 67h1M79 67h2M97 67h2M64 68h4M69 68h1M79 68h1M97 68h1M64 69h4M78 69h1M96 69h1M63 70h4M69 70h1M78 70h1M96 70h1M63 71h5M71 71h1M77 71h1M95 71h1M63 72h4M69 72h1M94 72h1M63 73h3M67 73h1M76 73h1M94 73h1M63 74h4M69 74h1M75 74h2M93 74h1M63 75h3M67 75h1M71 75h1M75 75h1M92 75h2M63 76h4M69 76h1M72 76h1M75 76h1M92 76h1M63 77h3M67 77h1M71 77h1M75 77h1M92 77h1M63 78h4M68 78h2M72 78h1M75 78h1M92 78h1M111 78h1M62 79h6M71 79h1M76 79h1M93 79h1M62 80h7M70 80h3M62 81h9M72 81h2M62 82h11M74 82h1M62 83h12M75 83h1M77 83h1M79 83h1M83 83h1M87 83h1M89 83h1M62 84h17M80 84h3M84 84h3M88 84h1M90 84h1M92 84h4M62 85h33M96 85h3M62 86h19M82 86h1M84 86h2M87 86h1M89 86h1M91 86h1M62 87h9M72 87h1M74 87h2M77 87h1M80 87h1M83 87h1M94 87h1M62 88h7M70 88h2M73 88h2M111 88h3M62 89h5M68 89h1M70 89h1M111 89h2M63 90h5M69 90h1M71 90h1M63 91h6M70 91h1M72 91h1M63 92h6M64 93h4M69 93h1M71 93h1M64 94h5M70 94h1M72 94h1M65 95h5M71 95h1M73 95h1M66 96h5M72 96h1M66 97h6M73 97h1M75 97h1M67 98h6M74 98h1M68 99h7M69 100h5M77 100h1M70 101h6M70 102h5M76 102h1M71 103h5M71 104h6M79 104h1M72 105h6M70 106h1M73 106h5M70 107h1M74 107h5M74 108h5M81 108h1M75 109h3M79 109h1M75 110h4M75 111h5M76 112h4M81 112h1M76 113h3M76 114h4M76 115h4M76 116h4M82 116h1M113 116h1M76 117h5M76 118h4M76 119h4M76 120h4M81 120h1M83 120h1M111 120h1M77 121h6M77 122h4M110 122h1M78 123h6M85 123h1M109 123h2M78 124h4M83 124h2M108 124h3M79 125h3M83 125h2M87 125h1M107 125h2M80 126h7M88 126h1M105 126h3M80 127h6M87 127h1M89 127h1M103 127h3M79 128h1M81 128h11M101 128h4M79 129h1M82 129h20M79 130h1M87 130h6M94 130h7M79 131h1M79 132h1 M111 70h1M111 71h1M110 72h1M110 73h1M109 74h1M109 75h1M109 76h1M108 77h1M108 78h1M108 79h1M107 80h1M107 81h1M107 82h1M106 83h1M106 84h1M105 85h1M105 86h1M105 87h1M105 88h1M106 89h1M106 90h1M107 91h1M108 92h1M109 93h1M110 94h1M110 95h1M111 96h1M111 97h1M112 98h1M112 99h1M112 100h1M113 101h1M113 102h1M114 103h1M114 104h1M61 105h1M114 105h1M61 106h1M114 106h1M61 107h1M114 107h1M61 108h1M70 108h1M114 108h1M61 109h2M70 109h1M114 109h1M61 110h1M70 110h1M114 110h1M61 111h1M69 111h1M114 111h1M114 112h1M61 113h1M69 113h1M71 113h1M114 113h1M61 114h2M69 114h1M71 114h1M114 114h1M62 115h1M70 115h2M113 115h2M70 116h1M114 116h1M112 117h3M81 118h1M112 118h2M80 119h1M111 119h3M112 120h1M110 121h1M112 121h1M81 122h1M109 122h1M112 122h1M108 123h1M107 124h1M82 125h1M106 125h1M93 131h1M91 132h1M90 133h1M80 134h1M90 134h1M93 134h1M109 134h1M80 135h1M90 135h1M93 135h1M109 135h1M76 136h1M80 136h1M90 136h1M94 136h1M109 136h1M76 137h1M80 137h1M90 137h1M95 137h1M109 137h2M76 138h1M80 138h1M89 138h1M95 138h1M76 139h1M80 139h1M90 139h1M95 139h1M110 139h1M75 140h1M80 140h1M95 140h1M110 140h1M75 141h1M80 141h1M90 141h1M95 141h1M110 141h2M75 142h1M80 142h1M90 142h1M95 142h1M111 142h1M75 143h1M80 143h1M90 143h2M95 143h1M74 144h1M80 144h1M91 144h1M95 144h1M111 144h1M74 145h2M80 145h1M95 145h1M111 145h1M74 146h1M81 146h1M95 146h1M112 146h1M81 147h1M93 147h1M112 147h2M75 148h1M81 148h1M75 149h1M81 149h1M75 150h1M81 150h1M75 151h2M81 151h1M75 152h2M81 152h1M76 153h2M81 153h1M76 154h6M77 155h3"></path>
    <path stroke="#a17124" d="M78 42h1M76 43h1M75 44h1M74 45h1M73 46h1M72 47h1M71 48h1M70 50h1M69 51h1M68 52h1M68 53h1M67 54h1M67 55h1M66 56h2M66 57h1M65 58h2M65 59h1M64 60h2M64 61h1M64 62h1M63 63h2M63 64h1M63 65h1M62 66h2M62 67h1M62 68h1M61 69h2M61 70h1M61 71h1M61 72h1M61 73h1M60 74h2M60 75h1M60 76h1M60 77h1M59 78h2M59 79h1M59 80h1M59 81h1M59 82h1M59 83h1M59 84h1M59 85h1M109 85h1M59 86h1M109 86h1M59 87h1M109 87h2M59 88h1M110 88h1M59 89h1M59 90h1M60 91h1M60 92h1M60 93h1M60 94h2M60 95h3M60 96h3M60 97h4M60 98h5M60 99h2M65 99h1M60 100h2M66 100h1M60 101h1M67 101h1M60 102h2M68 102h1M60 103h2M68 103h1M59 104h1M59 105h1M58 106h2M58 107h2M58 108h1M72 108h1M58 109h1M73 109h1M58 110h2M68 110h1M73 110h1M58 111h1M74 111h1M58 112h1M67 112h1M74 112h1M58 113h2M67 113h1M74 113h1M58 114h2M67 114h1M74 114h1M58 115h2M68 115h1M74 115h1M58 116h2M68 116h1M74 116h1M59 117h2M69 117h1M74 117h1M60 118h2M74 118h1M74 119h1M74 120h1M75 121h1M75 122h1M76 123h1M76 124h1M77 125h2M78 126h1M110 126h1M78 127h1M110 127h1M78 128h1M109 128h1M78 129h1M80 129h2M102 129h3M109 129h1M78 130h1M82 130h5M101 130h1M109 130h1M77 131h1M87 131h5M94 131h8M109 131h1M77 132h1M90 132h1M93 132h1M77 133h1M93 133h1M76 134h1M89 134h1M76 135h1M89 135h1M75 136h1M75 137h1M75 138h1M88 138h1M75 139h1M88 139h1M74 140h1M88 140h1M74 141h1M88 141h1M109 141h1M74 142h1M88 142h1M109 142h1M89 143h1M109 143h1M73 144h1M90 144h1M109 144h1M73 145h1M90 145h1M110 145h1M73 146h1M90 146h1M110 146h1M73 147h1M91 147h1M111 147h1M73 148h1M92 148h2M111 148h1M73 149h1M73 150h1M73 151h1M74 152h1M75 153h1M75 154h1M76 155h1M77 156h1"></path>
    <path stroke="#000000" d="M83 56h4M101 56h4M82 57h6M100 57h6M81 58h8M100 58h7M81 59h9M99 59h9M81 60h9M99 60h9M81 61h9M99 61h9M81 62h9M99 62h9M81 63h9M99 63h9M81 64h9M99 64h9M81 65h9M99 65h9M81 66h8M99 66h8M81 67h8M99 67h8M80 68h8M98 68h8M79 69h8M97 69h8M79 70h8M97 70h8M78 71h8M96 71h8M77 72h9M95 72h9M77 73h8M95 73h8M77 74h8M94 74h8M76 75h8M94 75h8M76 76h8M93 76h8M76 77h7M93 77h8M76 78h7M93 78h7M77 79h6M94 79h6M78 80h4M95 80h4M99 88h4M75 89h4M100 89h2M76 90h2M101 90h2M77 91h1M102 91h1M77 92h2M102 92h2M78 93h2M103 93h2M79 94h1M104 94h1M79 95h2M104 95h2M80 96h2M105 96h1M81 97h1M105 97h2M81 98h2M106 98h2M82 99h1M107 99h1M82 100h1M107 100h1M82 101h2M107 101h2M83 102h1M108 102h1M83 103h2M108 103h1M84 104h1M108 104h2M84 105h2M109 105h1M85 106h1M109 106h1M86 107h1M109 107h1M86 108h1M109 108h1M86 109h1M109 109h1M86 110h1M109 110h1M86 111h1M108 111h2M86 112h2M108 112h1M87 113h1M108 113h1M87 114h1M108 114h1M87 115h1M107 115h2M87 116h1M107 116h1M87 117h1M106 117h2M88 118h1M105 118h2M88 119h1M105 119h1M88 120h2M104 120h2M89 121h2M103 121h2M90 122h3M101 122h3M92 123h2M99 123h3M93 124h7"></path>
</svg>
```